# Haskell Cabal: locally fix a broken package DL'ed from Hackage

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Suppose that I ran `cabal sandbox init` .. `cabal install -j some-package` and got a build failure in one of dependencies of `some-package`.  One way to solve this is I notify the author of the failure and then wait for them to release a new version, but the process can sometimes be too slow.  When the reason of the failure is obvious (which is often the case,) I want to launch my text editor and fix it by myself.

However when I ran `find(1)` for the filename from the error log in `.cabal-sandbox` cache directory, I could find no `.hs` files.  Does the `cabal` command remove the entire source directory when GHC successfully or unsuccessfully finishes its execution?  How can I intrude into `cabal`'s task executions?  Or, are there any standardized way to achieve my original goal of fixing software packages from Hackage by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download package source with `cabal get <package>` then fix it and install into sandbox with `cabal install <package-dir>`.

E.g.

```
$ cabal get split
Unpacking to split-0.2.2/
$ vim split-0.2.2/split.cabal
$ cabal install ./split-0.2.2
```

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try!  I didn't know `cabal` accepts a local file path.

Comment: At first I thought it didn't work, but it turned out the `/` character at the end of the package name was essential for `cabal` to recognize it was a local directory, not on Hackage.